# WPF DataGrid how to get when ItemsSource updates

Tags: wpf, events, datagridview, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

Which event fires when DataGrid's source is updating? I've tried DataContextChanged and SourceUpdated but it never worked out.

Actually I need a simple thing. I want, if there is a new row comes, scroll the GridView's scrollbar down to the bottom to see what it was.

Comment: When you say "when a new rows comes in" do you mean to the underlying datasource (database) or to the DataGrid datasource?

Comment: I meant that the GridView's ItemsSource.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had the same problem and I manage it this way

```
DataGrid myGrid = new DataGrid();
CollectionView myCollectionView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myGrid.Items);
((INotifyCollectionChanged)myCollectionView).CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(DataGrid_CollectionChanged);
```

You then need to implement the logic in the event handler `DataGrid_CollectionChanged`.

Answer (score 8):

Set NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true for the ItemsSource binding and handle TargetUpdated event. If you've multiple bindings, then look for DataTransferEventArgs Property to find out if the target is ItemsSource or not.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to have the grid refresh when something is added to the database itself, that's not going to happen.  I'm more familiar with WinForms than WPF but I'm assuming there is no magical way to keep a grid in sync with the database without writing some background process that continuously checks for database changes.

If you are updating the actual data source of the grid (ex. Collection) then that will update the grid.

Comment: Yes I have some collection, and it's binded with GridView through ItemsSource.

Comment: Actually, one of the advantages of WPF over WinForms is the ability to Bind an a grid to a dataset and have the UI update automagically

Answer (score 2):

For my part i've used SelectionChange notification which raise each event Del/Add/Edit/Select
It's work very well

```
private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("hi");
}
```